# How to "add" a parse error from an action in Jison?

Tags: parsing, error-handling, bison, jison

Is there a way to add a parse error from an action in Jison? Say I have something like this:

```
some_element
    : text '.' text
        { 
            if ($3 === "SOMETHING3")
                // somehow add/throw a syntax error from here?
        }
    | text
        { $$ = { name: $1 }; }
    ;
```

I would like that "throw" to get recognized by the parser and provide me with an error such as this (which would be a standard parsing error normally, generated by rules):

```
Parse error on line 1:
SOMETHING1.SOMETHING3
-----------^
Expecting 'SOMETHING1', 'SOMETHING2', got 'SOMETHING3'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can call parseError from a rule, but you'd need to set up the dictionary yourself. (How else would the framework know what was "expected" if you don't tell it.)

Comment: I thought maybe through function params.. Anyway, I'll give it a go, thanks.